# cURL using login not working

Tags: bash, api, curl

I have the following problem that my curl request with login isn’t working. I tried different things I saw on stack overflow but I couldn’t get this working.

My AXIS-Camera has an API to access some data like the date and much more. On the browser I use a link like this:

```
http://root:root@IP/axis-cgi/date.cgi?action=get
```

The feedback is this:

```
Nov 20, 2017 14:27:00
```

Using curl:

```
curl "http://root:root@IP/axis-cgi/date.cgi?action=get"
```

or:

```
curl –user "root:root" "http://IP/axis-cgi/date.cgi?action=get"
```

I always get this result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document 
requested. Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Axis requires `Digest` mode for the auth, and `curl` doesn't use it by default.

Try this:

```
curl --digest -u root:root http://IP/axis-cgi/date.cgi?action=get
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this on an Axis 231D+ PTZ that I'm trying to figure out.  Firmware 4.47.  API version is probably really old.  But this worked:

```
curl http://user:pass@host/axis-cgi/admin/date.cgi?action=get
```

I've been looking through the cgi directories trying to figure out where stuff lives.  I think you may have missed a directory in your path.  Or this camera has it in a different place.  Hope this helps someone else too.

I do:

```
curl --digest -u user:pass http://host/axis-cgi/admin/uptime.cgi
```

And it does this:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized</H1>
Your client does not have permission to get URL /axis-cgi/admin/uptime.cgi from this server.
</BODY></HTML
```